# Null pointer when I call method EJB on server startup function using scheduler

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, wildfly

Hello everybody I try to reach a method EJB when i start server WildFly and I want that the method be excuted every 5s that's why i used the class Schedular  but the problem  is that when I execute the server this exception appears to me

> 02:12:54,738 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Map-JavaEE-ear/Map-JavaEE-ejb/ProjectService!tn.esprit.Map.interfaces.ProjectRemote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.Map-JavaEE-ear.Map-JavaEE-ejb."ProjectService!tn.esprit.Map.interfaces.ProjectRemote"
>   02:12:54,738 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
>   02:12:54,738 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
>   02:12:54,738 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:235)
>   02:12:54,738 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
>   02:12:54,738 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
>   02:12:54,738 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>   02:12:54,738 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>   02:12:54,738 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at tn.esprit.Map.utilities.Schedular.run(Schedular.java:23)
>   02:12:54,738 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
>   02:12:54,738 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

And this is my ClassService

```
@Stateless
public class ProjectService implements ProjectRemote {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MAP")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public List<Project> getAllProjects() {
    Query query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT p.id ,p.projectName , p.startDate" + " , p.endDate , p.address , p.totalNumberResource ,"
                    + " p.levioNumberResource,p.picture, p.projectType  FROM Project p");
    List<Object[]> res = query.getResultList();
    List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
    res.forEach(array -> {
        Project project = arrayToProject(array);
        projects.add(project);
    });

    return projects;
}

public Project arrayToProject(Object[] array){
    Project project = new Project();
    project.setId((int) array[0]);
    project.setProjectName((String) array[1]);
    project.setStartDate((Date) array[2]);
    project.setEndDate((Date) array[3]);
    project.setAddress((String) array[4]);
    project.setTotalNumberResource((int) array[5]);
    project.setLevioNumberResource((int) array[6]);
    project.setPicture((String) array[7]);
    project.setProjectType((ProjectType) array[8]);

    return project;
}
    @Override
public String archiveProject() throws ParseException {
    List<Project> projects = this.getAllProjects();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    ArchivedProjects archivedProjects = new ArchivedProjects();
    for (Project project : projects) {
        archivedProjects.setId(project.getId());
        archivedProjects.setProjectName(project.getProjectName());
        archivedProjects.setProjectType(project.getProjectType());
        archivedProjects.setAddress(project.getAddress());
        archivedProjects.setClient(project.getClient());
        archivedProjects.setStartDate(project.getStartDate());
        archivedProjects.setEndDate(project.getEndDate());
        archivedProjects.setLevioNumberResource(project.getLevioNumberResource());
        archivedProjects.setTotalNumberResource(project.getTotalNumberResource());
        archivedProjects.setOrganizationalChart(project.getOrganizationalChart());
        archivedProjects.setPicture(project.getPicture());
        if ((dateFormat.format(date).compareTo(project.getEndDate().toString()) > 0)) {
            em.remove(em.contains(project) ? project : em.merge(project));
            em.persist(em.contains(archivedProjects) ? archivedProjects : em.merge(archivedProjects));
        }

        System.out.println(project.getEndDate().toString() + "   " + dateFormat.format(date).toString());
    }
    return "Archived";

}
```

My schedular class :

```
@ManagedBean
public class Schedular extends TimerTask{
@EJB
ProjectRemote projectRemote;
@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        projectRemote.archiveProject();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

and finally where i call the EJB Method :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StartUpService extends HttpServlet {

Schedular sc = new Schedular();
public void init() throws ServletException {
    Timer timer = new  Timer()  ;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(sc,5000,1000);
}
}
```

Can anyone help Please  ?

Comment: If the ProjectService is deployed in another jar or EAR from Scheduler class you must use @EJB(lookup="[JNDI portable name]").

Comment: i hve try it but it didn't work :/

Comment: Can you tell where the class Schedular must be ? in the project EJB or WEB ?

Comment: I always use EJB Timer service and put it in the project EJB.

Comment: What can be the solution ? i tried every thing i always tried to run it in the WEB project i got the same exception

Comment: you need to take care with instantiating threads in the EJB container.  that is pretty much a "no-no".  you should be using "@Scheduled" or "@Asynchronous".  executing an ejb's methods in a thread that is not managed by the container can cause "interesting things".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add annotation LocalBean in your service.

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ProjectService implements ProjectRemote {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MAP")
private EntityManager em;
/**/
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer finaly worked! i have to work with Local Interface and add @LocalBean to my service

Answer (score 3):

You could add the following singleton to your EJB module( or add schedule annotation at archiveProject method)

```
@Singleton
    public class ProjectArchivingScheduler {

        @EJB
        ProjectRemote projectRemote;

        @Schedule(minute = "*", hour = "*", second = "*/5", persistent = false)
        public void refresh() {
            projectRemote.archiveProject();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer  but my problem that i can't reach the methode EJB from methode init() because i want that the method runs when the server start .

Comment: You could annotate the singleton bean with  Startup and call method in PostConstruct callback

Comment: This is how I do it as well!